# XPath: finding divs containing certain tags

Tags: python, html, xml, xpath, lxml

I know that it allows you to find a div with an `<a>` tag using

```
'//div[a]'
```

but what if I want a div with both an `<a>` tag AND a `<p>` tag.

I tried doing `'//div[a][p]'`.

I also tried doing `'//div[a|p]'` which I thought would give divs with either `<a>` or `<p>` tags and then I could check if that `<div>` contained an `<a>` and a `<p>` later... but none of the returned divs contain a `<p>`, just `<a>`'s even though I know there are `<div>`s containing both.

Comment: Do you want to only select `div` elements that have `a` or `p` elements as direct children or as descendants? Can you show an example page?

Comment: The a and p don't have to be direct children. They just both have to be anywhere at all inside the div.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to select only the `<div>` elements that have `<a>` and `<p>` as **children** (immediate descendants) then your XPath expressions are correct and the problem lies elsewhere.

If you mean to select `<div>` elements that **contain** `<a>` and `<p>`, you should use the `descendant` axis instead.

```
//div[descendant::a and descendant::p]
```

It will select all of the following `<div>`

```
<root>
  <div>
    <a>Dolor</a>
    <p>et calculum</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a>Dolor<p>et calculum</p></a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Foo</a><li>
    </ul>
    <p>Bar</p>
  </div>
</root>
```

Comment: Doesn't your expression include both the first `Lorem` and the later `Ipsum` divs? The OP *only* wants divs with *both* `a` *and* `p` contained, not *or*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I misread the latter part of the original post. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Using descendant seems to work- but instead of returning all divs that match this criteria, do you know of a way for it to choose the one that would result in the smallest container- the inner most div- the one with level closest to the a and p tag?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the last one will be the lowest in the element tree and therefore the one I'm looking for? I've tried with one example and it seems to be the case.

Comment: @user1136342 is it possible for a `div` to contain another `div` containing `a` and `p` **as well as** `a` and `p` elements that aren't enclosed in a `div`? As in `<div class="outer2">
 <div class="inner2">
  <div>
   <a>Dolor</a>
   <p>et calculum</p>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a>foo</a>
 <p>bar</p>
</div>` What should be selected in such case?

Comment: @Tom I want the smallest container that contains both so in this case, I'd want the third div with no class. A rough approximation to the smallest container would be fine too.

Comment: I think the logic from your earlier comment is what I'd be looking for. Just not sure about the syntax

Comment: @user1136342 in the above case, the outermost `div` is also the innermost container for `<a>foo</a>` and `<p>bar</p>`. If that's unrelated and you just want the most deeply-nested `div`s containing both `a` and `p`, the following expression should do: `//div[a][p][not(.//div[a][p])]`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a nicer way, but an immediate kludge is something like:

```
set(tree.xpath('//div[a]')).intersection(tree.xpath('//div[p]'))
```

Or this monstrosity keeping to plain XPath:

```
tree.xpath('//div[a][count(. | //div[p]) = count(//div[p])]')
```

If `lxml` used XPath 2.0 - then you'd have an intersect operator, but alas...